# Unpredictable state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am dynamically creating [`mathlive`](https://cortexjs.io/mathlive/) fields and adding them to the DOM.

Though it isn't a good way but doing it like this because I wasn't able to add the element as a React component and I needed a workaround quickly

Now when I remove an element from array responsible for rendering the elements, it works as expected but when the input event is fired on any of the remaining `mathlive` fields, the array comes back into the previous state before the element was removed.

```
const defaultOptions = [
    { text: '' },
    { text: '' },
    { text: '' },
    { text: '' },
]
const [options, setOptions] = useState(defaultOptions)

useEffect(() => {
    if (isPhysicsMathType) {
        options.map((option, i) => {
            addMathfield(option, i)
        })
    }
}, [isPhysicsMathType])

const addMathfield = (option, i) => {
    const mfe = new MathfieldElement()
    mfe.setAttribute('virtual-keyboard-mode', 'manual')
    mfe.value = option.text
    mfe.addEventListener('input', ev => {
        handleOptionChanged(ev, i)
    })
    let parent = null;
    const elementSelectInterval = setInterval(() => {
        parent = document.querySelector('.mathfield' + i)
        if (parent) {
            parent.appendChild(mfe)
            clearInterval(elementSelectInterval)
        }
    }, 50)
}
```

Rmoving the last option from the `options` array

```
const handleRemoveOption = () => {
    const choices = [...options]
    choices.pop()
    setOptions(choices)
}
```

Rendering elements

```
options.map((option, i) => {
 return <div key={"option" + i} className={'mathfield' + i}></div>
})
```

Comment: It sounds like something is using stale state (one of the classic bugs in React codebases) or it could be that you're not removing the `mathlive` element when removing it from the array (there doesn't seem to be a `removeMathField` here). But there isn't enough above for us to be able to help. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: I updated the question. No I am not removing them manually because they are rendered based on the options array. I think listeners are also destroyed with the elements. Do you think I should remove them manually?

Comment: Thanks for the added detail, but it still doesn't make it possible for us to replicate the problem. A runnable snippet is your best bet. *"Do you think I should remove them manually?"*  You're manually creating them, so unless something you haven't shown is clearing the container they're in, you need to manually remove them (or clear the container). (Side note: Using `map` just for side-effects is an antipattern, see [this post](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/) on my anemic blog.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by changing the `input` listener to `blur`. The issue was that I was always modifying the `options` array on every input (which is still weird why it wasn't working with that?). Now the options are modified after the blur event is fired on the `mathfield`.

```
mfe.addEventListener('blur', ev => {
  handleOptionChanged(ev, i)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out an important thing that needs to be taken care.

1. So the handler that you have `handleOptionChanged`, it is compiled when you initialize or update your app. In simple terms the params `ev` and `i` are the ones that bind to your `MathFieldElement()`'s handler when you create it.
2. Suppose you add `Math1` as first element, and then `Math2` as second one, The first handler is never aware that there exist another element after that, ****same works for deletion as in current case****, even you have updated the state array.
3. So when you fire input events from a particular `MathFieldElement` it will set whatever state it had used during its initialization to the current state.
4. **Solution**: You could add the handler after the initialization has happened, which means you provide a newly baked fresh handler to every element on re-render. Also refrain yourself from computing elements during initialization and keep its state. Like in the following example I have used state to store the input's value and not the input elements.

**Working example (Inspect console)** : https://codesandbox.io/embed/cranky-alex-r18hfg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
    export default function App() {
      const [maths, setmaths] = useState([]);
    
      const setMathValue = (id, value) => {
        let elementIndex = maths.findIndex((element) => element.id === id);
        maths[elementIndex] = { id: id, value: value };
        setmaths([...maths]);
      };
    
      const addMathElement = () => {
        setmaths([...maths, { id: maths.length + 1, value: "" }]);
      };
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <button onClick={addMathElement}>Add a math element</button>
          {maths.map((element) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <MathElement id={element.id} onChangeHandler={setMathValue} />
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

5. For your better understanding I have also made the erroneous code which will reset state value to its initial when ever it was created.

**Working example (Inspect console)**: https://codesandbox.io/embed/cranky-alex-r18hfg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
 export default function App() {
  const [maths, setmaths] = useState([]);
  const [mathElements, setMathElements] = useState([]);

  /*
     1. Create 2 elements
     2. Update both of them inspect state in the console
     3. Update the first element the data for the element should reset the state
     to when it was initialized
   */
  const setMathValue = (id, value) => {
    setmaths([...maths, { id: id, value: value }]);
  };

  const addMathElement = () => {
    let id = mathElements.length + 1;
    setMathElements([
      ...mathElements,
      <MathElement id={id} onChangeHandler={setMathValue} />
    ]);
  };

  console.log(maths);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={addMathElement}>Add a math element</button>
      {mathElements.map((element) => {
        return <div>{element}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The problem is that those math fields created with `new MathfieldElement()` are not React elements.